# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los objetos guardados en mi base de datos por mis usuarios aparezcan en el panel de administración de dajngo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Creo `Todo`, propuestas de coche compartido a partir de una plantilla que es gestionada por una vista. He visto que sean en db.sqlite3 pero, sin embargo no los veo guardados en el panel de administración (`127.0.0.1/admin/`).

De hecho, son visibles desde el sitio web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no los veo en el panel de administración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es porque he cambiado la gestión básica de usuarios añadiendo un CustomAccountManager en los modelos? En este caso, ¿tengo que crear una función create_todo? Pero realmente, ¿por qué no veo los todos en el panel de administración que están registrados?

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        # ... pensaba que no seria necesario anadirlo ...

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name,  company, mobile_number, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, first_name=first_name, 
                        company=company, mobile_number=mobile_number, password=password, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    # aqui necesito crear una funcion create_todo?


class Newuser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'mobile_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name


class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    memo = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Newuser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import TodoForm
from .models import Todo
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# ...

@login_required
def createtodo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/createtodo.html', {'form':TodoForm()})
    else:
        try:
            form = TodoForm(request.POST)
            newtodo = form.save(commit=False)
            newtodo.user = request.user
            newtodo.save()
            return redirect('currenttodos')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'todo/createtodo.html', {'form':TodoForm(), 'error':'Bad data passed in. Try again.'})

@login_required
def currenttodos(request):
    # todos = Todo.objects.filter(user=request.user, datecompleted__isnull=True)
    todos = Todo.objects.filter(datetime__gte=datetime.today())
    return render(request, 'todo/currenttodos.html', {'todos':todos})

# ...
```

`currenttodos.html`

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {% if todos %}
                 <h1>{{ todos.count }} Proposition{{ todos.count|pluralize }} de covoiturage</h1>
            {% else %}
                           <h1>Trajets proposés</h1>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        {% if todos %}
            <div class="list-group">
                {% for todo in todos %}
                    <a href="{% url 'viewtodo' todo.id %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action{% if todo.important %} list-group-item-danger{% endif %}"><b>{{ todo.title }} - {{ todo.datetime }}</b>, avec {{ todo.user }} {% if todo.memo %} - {{ todo.memo|truncatechars:30 }}{% endif %}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>Vous ne proposez pas de trajets pour le moments.</h2>
            <br>
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'createtodo' %}">Nouveau trajet</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: pregunta. Tus modelos los has agregado en el archivo admin.py?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba en el admin.py lo siguiente con el nombre adecuado de la app y modelo:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nombreapp.models import Todo
    
    class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
        list_display = ('datetime', 'car_type', 'memo','created','datecompleted','important','user')
    
    admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```